# How to save android image path in sqlite db and then after fetching and view in imageview

Tags: android, string, image, sqlite, android-resources

I plan to develop an android application for list with image and text.how can i save the image path(R.drawable.image) in sq lite db and then fetch that path and set to image view.for list items.

Comment: want you save the image's path witch are stored in the `drawable` directory?
If so, why you don't use simply `R.drawable.myImage` constant?

Comment: why because am creating db and insert data externally using sqlite browser window and insert data just application only view the data from the db only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read an image from `drawable` directory, but you have only the image name (NO the image path) you could get them from an `activity` like this:

```
Resources res = getResources();
int resId = res.getIdentifier("MY_IMAGE", "drawable", getPackageName());
if(resId==0) 
     throw new Exception("drawable resource not found");
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(resId);
```

And, in your `drawable` dir you will have a `MY_IMAGE.png` o what else.